# repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: mratwork-centalt

Tags: linux, repository, varnish

In My server, running Linux Redhat, I have NGINX, PHP Installed already.
Now I want to install PHP-FPM, VARNISH, APC, FASTCGI as well Memcache to speed up my server for my wordpress website.
I read this and so I want to install it in my server.
http://www.danielmiessler.com/blog/optimizing-wordpress-with-nginx-varnish-w3-total-cache-amazon-s3-and-memcached.
I have excidently done update and after that I get following error

```
yum install varnish
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, protectbase, replace
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirror.secureax.com
 * epel: mirror.nus.edu.sg
 * extras: centos.mirror.secureax.com
 * mratwork-epel: mirror.nus.edu.sg
 * remi: mirror.smartmedia.net.id
 * updates: centos.mirror.secureax.com
http://centos.alt.ru/repository/centos/6/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: mratwork-centalt. Please verify its path and try again
```

How to install varnish?

**Files**

**CentOS-Base.repo**

```
# CentOS-Base.repo
#
# The mirror system uses the connecting IP address of the client and the
# update status of each mirror to pick mirrors that are updated to and
# geographically close to the client.  You should use this for CentOS updates
# unless you are manually picking other mirrors.
#
# If the mirrorlist= does not work for you, as a fall back you can try the 
# remarked out baseurl= line instead.
#
#

[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6

#released updates 
[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=updates
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6

#additional packages that may be useful
[extras]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Extras
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=extras
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6

#additional packages that extend functionality of existing packages
[centosplus]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Plus
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=centosplus
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/centosplus/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6

#contrib - packages by Centos Users
[contrib]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Contrib
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=contrib
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/contrib/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
```

**CentOS-Debuginfo.repo**

```
# CentOS-Debug.repo
#
# The mirror system uses the connecting IP address of the client and the
# update status of each mirror to pick mirrors that are updated to and
# geographically close to the client.  You should use this for CentOS updates
# unless you are manually picking other mirrors.
#

# All debug packages from all the various CentOS-5 releases
# are merged into a single repo, split by BaseArch
#
# Note: packages in the debuginfo repo are currently not signed
#

[debug]
name=CentOS-6 - Debuginfo
baseurl=http://debuginfo.centos.org/6/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-Debug-6
enabled=0
```

**CentOS-Media.repo**

```
# CentOS-Media.repo
#
#  This repo can be used with mounted DVD media, verify the mount point for
#  CentOS-6.  You can use this repo and yum to install items directly off the
#  DVD ISO that we release.
#
# To use this repo, put in your DVD and use it with the other repos too:
#  yum --enablerepo=c6-media [command]
#  
# or for ONLY the media repo, do this:
#
#  yum --disablerepo=\* --enablerepo=c6-media [command]

[c6-media]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Media
baseurl=file:///media/CentOS/
        file:///media/cdrom/
        file:///media/cdrecorder/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
```

**CentOS-Vault.repo**

```
# CentOS-Vault.repo
#
# CentOS Vault holds packages from previous releases within the same CentOS Version
# these are packages obsoleted by the current release and should usually not 
# be used in production
#-----------------

[C6.0-base]
name=CentOS-6.0 - Base
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.0/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0

[C6.0-updates]
name=CentOS-6.0 - Updates
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.0/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0

[C6.0-extras]
name=CentOS-6.0 - Extras
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.0/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0

[C6.0-contrib]
name=CentOS-6.0 - Contrib
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.0/contrib/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0

[C6.0-centosplus]
name=CentOS-6.0 - CentOSPlus
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.0/centosplus/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0
#-----------------

[C6.1-base]
name=CentOS-6.1 - Base
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.1/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0

[C6.1-updates]
name=CentOS-6.1 - Updates
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.1/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0

[C6.1-extras]
name=CentOS-6.1 - Extras
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.1/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0

[C6.1-contrib]
name=CentOS-6.1 - Contrib
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.1/contrib/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0

[C6.1-centosplus]
name=CentOS-6.1 - CentOSPlus
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.1/centosplus/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0
#-----------------

[C6.2-base]
name=CentOS-6.2 - Base
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.2/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0

[C6.2-updates]
name=CentOS-6.2 - Updates
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.2/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0

[C6.2-extras]
name=CentOS-6.2 - Extras
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.2/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0

[C6.2-contrib]
name=CentOS-6.2 - Contrib
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.2/contrib/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0

[C6.2-centosplus]
name=CentOS-6.2 - CentOSPlus
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.2/centosplus/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0
#-----------------

[C6.3-base]
name=CentOS-6.3 - Base
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.3/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0

[C6.3-updates]
name=CentOS-6.3 - Updates
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.3/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0

[C6.3-extras]
name=CentOS-6.3 - Extras
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.3/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0

[C6.3-contrib]
name=CentOS-6.3 - Contrib
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.3/contrib/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0

[C6.3-centosplus]
name=CentOS-6.3 - CentOSPlus
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.3/centosplus/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0
#-----------------

[C6.4-base]
name=CentOS-6.4 - Base
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.4/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0

[C6.4-updates]
name=CentOS-6.4 - Updates
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.4/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0

[C6.4-extras]
name=CentOS-6.4 - Extras
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.4/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0

[C6.4-contrib]
name=CentOS-6.4 - Contrib
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.4/contrib/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0

[C6.4-centosplus]
name=CentOS-6.4 - CentOSPlus
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.4/centosplus/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0
```

Comment: CentALT repo is offline. He wants money for his work now. Don't use mirrors, they will not update anymore and might go down aswell.
Just dont use CentALT anymore... look for other alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue.  It seems as if the primary server is having issues.  I updated the repo baseurl to a mirror and got around the issue:

```
sudo vi /etc/yum.repos.d/centos.alt.ru.repo
```

Replace:

```
baseurl=http://centos.alt.ru/repository/centos/6/$basearch/
```

With:

```
baseurl=http://mirror.sysadminguide.net/centalt/repository/centos/6/$basearch/
```

and I was good to go.

Comment: I have added files, Where to replace line that you given? I am not getting it..

Comment: The above answer nails it. It is always better to have a mirror list than a single server.

Comment: Thank you *rbywater*. I ran also into the same issue on a centos 5 server, and replaced the baseurl with this mirror in /etc/yum.repos.d/centos.alt.ru.repo: `baseurl=http://mirror.sysadminguide.net/centalt/repository/centos/5/$basearch/`

Comment: Thanks @rbywater. The file for me was `/etc/yum.repos.d/centalt.repo`